# Parsing a csv file into a php array

Tags: php, csv, fgetcsv

I want to parse my csv file into an array but the problem is that the delimiter keeps changing and will be specified by the user.So user selects from a dropdown containing \t, \n, , , and | and is stored in $delimiter.

```
($lineRaw = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, $delimiter))
```

The above given line however doesn't provide an accurate result. Any suggestions on how to go about it?

Comment: How are you passing the dropdown value into the `$delimiter` variable? Assuming the dropdown's actual value is the string "\n" rather than the escape sequence \n (which would look like html whitespace) you will need to translate those string literals into the correct escape characters.

Comment: looks like that would work properly to me

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski thanks ! That was what the error was !